# How to remove load more and show pagination WordPress in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, jquery-plugins

i would like to remove load more and show pagination WordPress in Woocommerce

You can see the products with their title below:
[image]

Website link: http://filelives.com/

Comment: Can you let me know which theme you are using?

Comment: this one: https://demo.mekshq.com/?theme=voice

Comment: This functionality is added by your theme, not a default WP setting, so it would depend on how your theme is built

Comment: i want to add this feature in my website

Answer (score 1):

Click on 'Edit' of a particular module and click on 'Action' tab in the popup. Change 'Choose pagination type' to 'Numeric pagination links'.

[image]